# Firebase fetching data based on a particular key value

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase real time database. My data is mostly an array of records. For example:

```
opty = [ {"id":1,"name":"a"}, {"id":2, "name": "b"}]
```

I can access the entire dataset using:

```
https://<my project id>.firebaseio.com/opty.json
```

How do I fetch the record with an `id` of 2 here? I've tried to do the following:

`https://<my project id>.firebaseio.com/opty.json?OptyId=2`

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you right, you want to filter your data through the rest API.

To achieve that you can use the usual filter parameters as query strings:

```
https://<my project id>.firebaseio.com/opty.json?orderByKey="id"&startAt=2'
```

Learn more [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data).

Comment: yes you understood correct. however how does startAt will help here? id may be totally random number and does not have to be an ordered. Or take it this way: what id is actually not a number but a unique string which is used as key for each object?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? The question says you want to get the record with an `id` of 2.

Comment: my example happen to be bad i would say. How about finding the one with name = b.

Comment: just do `?orderByKey="name"&startAt=b`

Comment: will that work even if name in first object is 'abcd'  and 2nd object has 'kfljjfsg'   and say i want to find the one with value 'kfljjfsg'

Comment: yeah of course you just need to make the call dynamic. replace the value `?orderByKey="name"&startAt=kfljjfsg `

Comment: ok i thought startAt is trying to work with a sortable list etc.

Comment: i see one problem with this. the result comes like  {"1":{object}}   so basically it is adding the array index where the object exists in the json. i dont need that and just object.  it's not an array either as it doesnt start with [. and i wont know the key value to access in client side